# Character stack to check matching brackets no errors but also doesnt appear to do anything

Tags: java, stack

I took a half a year off from programming and now Im just refreshing my memory w super basic little interview questions...and Ive been stuck for 2 days on the first one.. Below is my code can someone just hint to me why the program shows no errors but upon compilation does nothing? It should ignore text characters but Im not even there yet

```
public class bracketCheck {

public static void main(String[] args) {


Stack <Character> s = new <Character> Stack(); 
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
String buff; 

System.out.println("please enter brackets & text");
buff = input.nextLine(); 
input.close();
int count = 0;
boolean cont = true;
Character stackTop;
Character current = buff.charAt(count);
do {
    if(current == ')' || current== '}' || current== ']') {
        s.push(current);
        count++;
    }
    else if(current== '(' || current== '{' || current== '[') {
        stackTop = s.pop();
        cont = match(stackTop, current);    
    }
}
while(s.isEmpty() == false /*&& cont =true*/); 
if(s.isEmpty())
    System.out.println("bout time......");

}

private static boolean match(Character top , Character not) {
    if(top == ')' && not == '(') 
        return true;
    else if(top == ']' && not == '[') 
        return true;
    else if(top == '}' && not == '{') 
        return true;
    else 
        return false;
}

}
```

Comment: What is the output that you get? What do you pass as `buff`?

Comment: Hey, before addressing your specific question, note that cont is not being read (you've commented it out) and that Stack<Character> s = new Stack<>(); is a better way to initialize s (which is not a good name for a variable)

Comment: @GBlodgett  java.util.Scanner[delimiters=\p{javaWhitespace}+][position=7][match valid=true][need input=false][source closed=true][skipped=false][group separator=\,][decimal separator=\.][positive prefix=][negative prefix=\Q-\E][positive suffix=][negative suffix=][NaN string=\Q�\E][infinity string=\Q∞\E]

Comment: @RoyShahaf My thinking was text one thing at a time. First at least check if braces are being pushed and popped since I dont know where the problem lies. idea was move 1 step at a time. As for the variable names, noted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I saw some issues in your code, this is my fixed version of it

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Stack;

// use Capital letters in the beginning of class names
public class BracketCheck {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Stack<Character> stack = new Stack<>();
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        String buff;

        System.out.println("please enter brackets & text");
        buff = input.nextLine();
        input.close();
        // using java8 makes iterating over the characters of a string easier
        buff.chars().forEach(current -> {
            // if <current> is an opening bracket, push it to stack
            if (current == '(' || current == '{' || current == '[') {
                stack.push((char) current);
            }
            // if <current> is a closing bracket, make sure it is matching an opening
            // bracket or alert and return
            else if (current == ')' || current == '}' || current == ']') {
                if (!match(stack, (char) current)) {
                    System.out.println("no good");
                    return;
                }
            }
        });
        // if, after we finished iterating the string, stack is empty, all opening
        // brackets had matching closing brackets
        if (stack.isEmpty()) {
            System.out.println("bout time......");
        }
        // otherwise, alert
        else {
            System.out.println("woah");
        }
    }

    private static boolean match(Stack<Character> stack, Character closer) {
        // if stack is empty, the closer has no matching opener
        if (stack.isEmpty()) {
            return false;
        } else {
            // get the most recent opener and verify it matches the closer
            Character opener = stack.pop();
            if (opener == '(' && closer == ')')
                return true;
            else if (opener == '[' && closer == ']')
                return true;
            else if (opener == '{' && closer == '}')
                return true;
            else
                return false;
        }
    }
}
```